# Rotating images and text

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I want to have an image with it's corresponding block of text rotating every few seconds on my website. Just like these guys http://hellofisher.com/

I know I can get a javascript to rotate the images but I haven't found where I can have the block of text alongside rotating to suit the images.

Comment: i see no rotations on that site

Comment: @neal - I thought so too, but you need to wait for a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show you a simple example which you can easily use on your site. This example uses 3 slides and isn't a dynamic slider where you can have as many slides as you want to but it's easy to edit it into one if the amount of slides can vary.

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="slider-area">
        <div class="slide">content</div>
        <div class="slide">content</div>
        <div class="slide">content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Slider is the visible area which the user can see, slider-area is the area where you put the slides and each slide contains a different image and text.

CSS:

```
#slider {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#slider-area {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.slide {
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
}
```

As you can see, slider-area's width is 3 times the size of slider because there are 3 slides. Slider has overflow: hidden which means scrollbar won't be visible and position: relative so that we can absolutely position the slider-area inside the slider. Then we simply insert slides inside the slider-area.

JS (using JQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer = setInterval(changeSlide, 5000);
});

function changeSlide() {
    var pos = $('#slider').attr('scrollLeft');
    if (pos==800)
        pos=0
    else
        pos=pos+400;
    $('#slider').animate({scrollLeft: pos}, 600, 'swing');
}
```

Here you set a timer which will call the changeSlide function every 5 seconds. The changeSlide function will take the current position of the slider's scrollbar and animate it accordingly. If it's displaying the last slide, next one will be the first slide (pos=0) and if it's not displaying the last slide, it adds 400 to the position so that it will scroll to the next slide. Basically the sliding animation is simply moving a hidden scrollbar with a timer.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just google for jquery content rotators or content sliders.  There's a million ready-made plugins already done like this:

[For example](http://designbeep.com/2010/05/13/25-very-detailed-jquery-image-and-content-slider-tutorials/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery to rotate out a `<div>` containing an image and associated text. Use `$.hide()` and `$.show()` and Javascript's time functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

JAVASCRIPT

```
var imagelist = ["IMAGE1","IMAGE2","IMAGE3"]
var textlist = ["TEXT1","TEXT2","TEXT3"];
counter=0;
countmax=3;
var next = function(){
    $('rotating_image').innerHTML="<img src=\"" imagelist[counter%countmax] + "\">";
    $('rotating_text').innerHTML=textlist[counter%countmax];
    countmax++;
}
var rotate = window.setInterval(next, SECONDS * 1000);
```

HTML

```
<span id="rotating_image"></span>
<span id="rotating_text"></span>
```

Comment: Or you could use `$('rotating_image').src=imagelist[counter%countmax]`, provided `rotating_image` is an image and not a span.